# Get Text of Item in Listbox by Value using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I get the text of an item in Listbox by passing the value of that item. I don't need the selected item, only the one I specified by value.

I use jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML Code:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">ayush</option>
</select>
```

jQuery Code:

```
var a = $('option[value="1"]').html();
console.log(a);
```